# No module named 'OWSlib'

Tags: python, gis

After doing some research on this, the only existing source referring directly to this does not also pour in any hope. Checked into environment - the library existing is called OWSLib==0.28.1, do capital letters in libraries tell something? A script? Unsuccessful with installing other versions also.

Ran the only command beforehand:

```
pip install owslib
```

Trying to access it:

```
import owslib
import owslib.wmts
from owslib.ogcapi.records import Records
```

Comment: Python is case sensitive, `OWSlib` and `owslib` are therefore completely different. Check if `pip` runs on the same Python `--version` as your Python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the command

```
pip install OWSLib
```

It should work. Let me know in case there are any other errors.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. The problem was actually where I didn't connect the virtual environment with the script via the kernel correctly.